# dynamic iframe height in isotope layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-isotope

I'm having problems positioning iframes in divs in an isotope layout.

EDIT See example here: http://beektest.co/index_test.html (click on one of the white divs with image and text in it to open iframe)

Basically the iframe is appearing half way down the div, and behind the isotope elements.

I've set the div to height 450, but when the iframe loads it seems to shrink to half of that, and the iframe is overlapping the div.

Any clues on how to force the iframe to the top of the div, and stop it resizing the div?

Here's the code:

```
        $("#container").append('<div id="item_'
                    + v.id + '" class="item"><a href="http://site.co/guide/'
                    + v.id + '--'
                    + urltitle + '"><img id="img_'
                    + v.id + '" src="http://cdn.site.co/' 
                    + v.thumbName + '" "width="200" height="200" /></a><p id="p_'
                    + v.id + '" align="center">' 
                    + desc + '</p></div>');

                $('#item_'
                + v.id + '').click(function(){
                    $(this).css('width','100%');
                    $('#img_'
                    + v.id + '').css('visibility','hidden');
                    $('#p_'
                    + v.id + '').css('visibility','hidden');

                    $(this).append('<iframe id="iframe" src="http://site.co/g'
                        + v.id + '"></iframe>');

                    var $container = $('#container');
                    $container.isotope('reLayout');

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        var position = $('#item_'+ v.id + '').position();
                        scroll(0,position.top);
                        $container.isotope('reLayout');
                    },1000);
                });
```

And here is the CSS

```
iframe
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    height: 450px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.item {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
     margin-right:10px;
     padding-right:10px;
     padding-top:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 100%);
     z-index: 1001;
}   

.large{
width: 600px;
height: 450px;
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net or plunker so people can see all your plugin settings and inspect css in console

Comment: I've uploaded http://beektest.co/index_test.html

Comment: everything looks fine for me in firefox.... I re sized window several times...not sure how to replicate or exactly where to look. What browser are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry I've not finished the buttons. Click on the white div around the text for it to expand and show the iframe.

Comment: suggest you set up simpler demo without videos in it...I get swfobject errors and blue area goes blank when i try to inspect with console. Still not sure what I should be looking at. Put a big `<h2>I am iframe</h2>` for content

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for looking.

The CSS wasn't getting called on the update, I was overwriting it manually elsewhere.

Thanks for looking.